# Exception: Cannot run program "E:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat"

Tags: flutter

I was working on project , I closed my android studio and then opened it again , I was trying to create a new project in flutter but suddenly an error appeared to me as posted below , I cannot run any commends like pub get , pub run , whenever I prefer any of them the error appears , if any one could help , that would be appreciated , I have checked most answers but none of them helped , i don't know what happened exactly . thank you

- This is the error

```
 Exception: Cannot run program "E:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" (in directory "E:\flutter\flutter"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

- This is a screenshot of the error appearing

[image]

- Envirenment Variables

[image]

Comment: Does the file exist at that location?

Comment: Yes it does but when i clicked on it , a windows shows up and says windows cannot find flutter.bat

Comment: Oh, so it appears in File Explorer, but if you try to execute it from there, Windows says it can't find it? That's unfortunate, and sounds like a Windows problem rather than a Flutter or IDE problem. As a workaround, I would just install Flutter to a new location, and set all your pointers to there. (Try rebooting first, if you haven't done that yet.)

Comment: Because i was working on flutter project yesterday , i closed it and went to rest little , then when i opened android studio again and tried to create a new project , it shows powershell error , then this error as well ..

Comment: Hmm, sounds pretty foreboding.

Comment: I'm moving the flutter sdk to different location , will update you soon after trying again , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to exclude exe or bat file name
for example, E:\flutter\flutter\bin   <<<enough, clean

and you can follow and guess through next sentences

if you are beginner like me, follow me. i will explain it detail. Windows7 case or something. I did for 3 days. finally, i found it

Basically, 1.git program already installed (on program files) 2.flutter.bat installed (C:\name(i did nee or see..whatever)\flutter\bin) dont install on program files

you did right? now, you meet to hell soon. you dont find flutter. 'where' what is path? what is right.... dont worry

Foysal Khandakar joy mentioned

for setting env = enviroment. you commend env and click we have a two type. User variable and System variable. Both are important. never wrong

If you want to addition Path, have to use ; semi-colon (in front of new path) for example, First, User Variable Path case

C:\nee\flutter\bin
C:\nee\flutter\bin;C:\nee\flutter (if you want for flutter_console)
but first is clean. enough. not important Second, System Variable Path case, You have to resister all together with ; C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Windows\System32

Another case, Someone can follow next. When you insert only first and third, maybe if you are typing flutter_console on cmd, guide will be appeared. Please insert your path. http:// some blabla~~~ You have to resister second path about powershell additionally on system variable.

if you follow, you can go to sleep ^^

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but i had an issue , my windows update messed up everything , i had to go back to a version of windows and it got fixed , thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Check Flutter Configuration in Android Studio:
Open Android Studio, go to File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter. Make sure the Flutter SDK path points to the correct Flutter installation directory (C:\Flutter)